# In angular project, using devextreme for UI components but facing issue for adding calendar icon in date box field

Tags: angular, frontend, devextreme

In the angular project, using **devextreme** for UI components but facing an issue with adding a calendar icon in the date box field

Showing like this [Date box field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxH26.png)

Expected like this [Required calendar icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB1hh.png)

````
                <dx-date-box [min]="today" [pickerType]="isMobileDevice ? 'rollers': 'calender'"
                             formControlName="estimated_delivery" id="job-basic-info-estimated_delivery"
                             placeholder="Select from calender" type="date">
                </dx-date-box>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `dropDownButtonTemplate` field on the component. Check out the [documentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDateBox/Configuration/#dropDownButtonTemplate)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.. But i made a mistake in spelling for **calendar** now issue resolved